# Where i should put data managers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is good practice for put data persisters in one place. For now i put model.save() in every controller when i save this object. But i think it is not good resolve, because it can make code duplicates.
I found in ember we have services https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/applications/services/, but according documentation it is place for not use data store.

My question is what is best practice for not duplicate data persist code?

Comment: Doing `model.save()` in the controllers is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending some base controller or maybe extending controllers with a mixin containing the actions and the logic? I think mixins would be the way to go for that.